# How can update db column status using date laravel

Tags: php, laravel

DB column status auto update using date value how can i do this.

Comment: can you explain it more ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, so its not likely to get any answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is very unclear, and unless you edit it and clarify, it is likely to be closed.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to set the `TIMESTAMP` column to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value, try this on your migration:

```php
Schema::table('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->timestamp('taking_off_at')->setCurrent();
});
```